# simple question about properly divergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Is it true that if a sequence $\{x_{n}\}$ has no properly divergent subsequence, then the sequence is bounded?

I think it is true intuitively considering subsequential limit but i’m not sure about that.

Give me some counter-example or comment. Thank you.

Comment: If the sequence is not bounded then either there is a subsequence strictly increasing to $\infty$ or there is a subsequence strictly decreasing to $-\infty$

Comment: Properly divergent sequence? What is the meaning of this, please?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Actually, I tried to show your statement in another way using the assumption as above leads a contradiction.

Comment: @dmtri diverges at plus/minus infinity not oscillate

Answer (score 1):

Equivalently, if a sequence is unbounded, it has a sub-sequence strictly increasing to $\infty$ or strictly decreasing to $-\infty.$

Let $(x_j)_{j\in \Bbb N}$ be an unbounded sequence in $\Bbb R$.

Let $n_1$ be the least $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $|x_n|>1.$ Define $n_{j+1}$ recursively as follows: Let $$y_j=\max (j+1, \max \{ |x_i|:1\leq i\leq n_j\}).$$ Let $n_{j+1}$ be the least $n\in \Bbb N$ such that $|a_n|>y_j.$

For every $j\in \Bbb N$ we have $j\leq n_j<n_{j+1}$ and $j<|x_{n_j}|<|x_{n_{j+1}}|.$

Let $S=\{j\in \Bbb N: x_{n_j}>j\}$ and $T=\{j\in \Bbb N: x_{n_j}<-j\}.$ We have $S\cup T=\Bbb N.$

If $S$ is an infinite set then the sequence $(x_{n_j})_{j\in S}$ strictly increases to $\infty.$

If $T$ is an infinite set then $(x_{n_j})_{j\in T}$ strictly decreases to $-\infty.$